# Excel 2007 crashing when saving workbook after running macro

Tags: excel, vba, crash, save

I am using Excel 2007 (32Bit) on a Windows 7 64Bit machine.

I have a large Workbook with 12 sheets and 18 VBA modules.

All of my subroutines run flawlessly but one is causing the following issue:

The macro itself runs from start to finish successfully just as specified. After running the macro successfully, the workbook crashes, when I try to save it. It also crashes when AutoSave tries to save the workbook. The workbook does not crash when I simply close it.
By crashing, I mean that I get the message "Microsoft Office Excel has stopped working".

In the Windows Event Viewer I have identified the error message 0xc0000005.

In the folder where the workbook is saved, I find the temporary files that Excel creates when saving a workbook (named something like  9BB7B000).

I have tried to repair Excel in the Programs and Features part of the Control Panel but it has not worked. Furthermore no Add-Ins are enabled.

I suspected that the code module of the problem-causing macro was too large (90KB) so I split it up into two modules smaller than 64KB. However, the problem remains.

I would appreciate any help on this issue. I would like to get around reconstructing the workbook manually, if possible, as that would mean an enormous effort.

Thank you very much in advance.

Jochen

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue some time ago and carried out a research to identify the issue to no avail.

I noticed that it worked fine on workstations with better procs and more ram.

However the only way for me to proceed was to create a new workbook a one-by-one copy each worksheet from the old workbook and see which one is causing the issue. If the macro is causing the error then try to add a "sleep" command between loops so that the Excel file regains control and can execute and awaiting events/commands.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I added Sleep commands in the code but unfortunately the problem remains. I will try out the other possibilities that you have mentioned (different workstation and one-by-one approach).

Answer (score 0):

The post was 9 months ago, could you fix it?

What does that specific macro do? Because there are several solutions to this problem.

It seems that a certain "action" in your macro takes too long. 
You can search for that specific action and us `application.wait` to slow your macro down. If this doesn't work, you'll have to find a way to reduce the "workload". But to do that, i'll need to take a look at your code.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the AutoSave function in Excel Options

Comment: Can you explain how this answers the question? *[How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)*